# stream_get_contents replacing plus with space

Tags: php

So this is something that I have not been able to find any documentation on. I have a plain text string that I am trying to turn into a stream in php.

```
$myStr = "A bit of text +test +test2";
$stream = fopen('data://text/plain,' . $myStr, 'r');
var_dump(stream_get_contents($stream);
```

The output of this code is

```
A bit of text  test  test2
```

I tried using preg_replace to add an escape to the plus signs however this did not seem to have any effect. Any other ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [base64_encode](http://php.net/base64_encode):

```
$myStr = "A bit of text +test +test2";
$stream = fopen('data://text/plain;base64,' . base64_encode($myStr), 'r');
var_dump(stream_get_contents($stream));
```

[Here's an example](http://codepad.org/Fs5cAZNz).

The reason for the issue is that it's a URI, and in HTTP URIs a `+` is an encoded space. Your other choice is to use [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) ([example](http://codepad.org/aW5hpROT)).

Comment: That did work, thank you. Do you know why the other method caused that problem?

Comment: Was just writing that edit :-) The URI is assumed by PHP to be HTTP, so `+` is decoded to a space by the stream.